# checking 2 sql columns and displaying result in 1 column

Tags: sql, logic, case

ok..i have 2 tables...they are exactly the same except for the column name in one of them because they deal with 2different "companies", though..the data i want is in columns that have the same name.pretty much what i want to do...is **if tableA.Col2 is > 0 or tableB.Col2 is > 0 then 1**..else 0..they also need to be distinct...i can get them as separate tables...but i cant get them together..I need them in 1 column because of how it is sent to the C3 code page and how it reads it...the structure has already been previously set..and there are about 5 other statments that are being executed in this one stored procedure like this (also i wasnt the one who set this up). So if f this is possible..let me know please.. i will also paste the exact code i have if you feel like seeing the real life code..i just tried to simplify it to make it easier to understand.

```
DECLARE @id INT;
DECLARE @invest nvarchar(50);
SET @id = '7633';
SET @invest = '';


SELECT 'a' + CONVERT(nvarchar, orderfindings.risk_rating) AS cat, COUNT(DISTINCT orderfindings.prnt_id) AS stat
        FROM orderheader, orderaudits, orderfindings
        WHERE orderheader.id = orderaudits.orderheader_id AND orderaudits.ID = orderfindings.prnt_id
        AND orderheader.id = @id AND orderfindings.risk_rating > 0 AND orderaudits.Investor_Name LIKE '%' + @invest + '%'
        GROUP BY orderfindings.risk_rating
UNION ALL
SELECT 'a' + CONVERT(nvarchar, orderagencies.risk_rating) AS cat, COUNT(DISTINCT orderagencies.prnt_id) AS stat
        FROM orderheader, orderaudits, orderagencies
        WHERE orderheader.id = orderaudits.orderheader_id AND orderaudits.ID = orderagencies.prnt_id
        AND orderheader.id = @id AND orderagencies.risk_rating > 0 AND orderaudits.Investor_Name LIKE '%' + @invest + '%'
        GROUP BY orderagencies.risk_rating

-------------------
/*
Results from 1st statement
cat | stat
-----------
a1  |  4
-----------
a2  |  5
-----------

Results from 2nd statement
cat | stat
-----------
a1  |  3
-----------
a2  |  2
-----------

I pretty much want

Results from new awesome statement
cat | stat
-----------
a1  |  5
-----------
a2  |  5
-----------
I think those are the numbers that would be accurate
Simple version---    if tableA.Col2 is > 0 or tableB.Col2 is > 0 then 1 else 0
  |Table A                |               Table B                 |    result of query
  |   col_1     col2      |      col_1               col2         |
  --------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |   1           5       |       1                   3           |          1
2 |   1           45      |       1                   0           |          1
3 |   1           0       |       1                   0           |          0  
4 |   1           0       |       1                   3           |          1

so a1 would be 3...4 records in the tables..but only 3 of them matter because row 3 has 0 
whatevers in col 2 for both tables..there might be 100 records that have 1 for col 1..there 
might only be 1
```

i hope this makes more sense...it is kinda a weird task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @id INT;
DECLARE @invest nvarchar(50);
SET @id = '7633';
SET @invest = '';


SELECT  Findings.cat [cat], 
        CASE WHEN Findings.stat > 0 OR Agencies.stat > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [stat]

FROM (SELECT 'a' + CONVERT(nvarchar, orderfindings.risk_rating) AS cat, COUNT(DISTINCT orderfindings.prnt_id) AS stat
        FROM orderheader, orderaudits, orderfindings
        WHERE orderheader.id = orderaudits.orderheader_id AND orderaudits.ID = orderfindings.prnt_id
        AND orderheader.id = @id AND orderfindings.risk_rating > 0 AND orderaudits.Investor_Name LIKE '%' + @invest + '%'
        GROUP BY orderfindings.risk_rating) Findings
INNER JOIN (SELECT 'a' + CONVERT(nvarchar, orderagencies.risk_rating) AS cat, COUNT(DISTINCT orderagencies.prnt_id) AS stat
        FROM orderheader, orderaudits, orderagencies
        WHERE orderheader.id = orderaudits.orderheader_id AND orderaudits.ID = orderagencies.prnt_id
        AND orderheader.id = @id AND orderagencies.risk_rating > 0 AND orderaudits.Investor_Name LIKE '%' + @invest + '%'
        GROUP BY orderagencies.risk_rating) Agencies

ON Findings.cat = Agencies.cat
```

Comment: that definitely works...but i feel like i may have messed up my logic on this and in how i presented it..have to go through it in my head..thanks for the help though1 going to mark this as answer. Probably will have to do a new question once i figure this out

Comment: if you want to give it another shot..here is new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130318/checking-2-sql-columns-and-displaying-result-in-1-column-pt2  ..i think i did a better job explaining what i need haha..i hope

Answer (score 1):

You can use another level of subquery to include them in summary result
like from your example here.

```
Select cat , SUM(stat) as stat
FROM
(
  YOUR FIRST QUERY
  UNION ALL
  YOUR SECOND SECOND QUERY 
) AS subquery
GROUP BY cat
```

Comment: i get incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'..also..wouldnt this just be adding the results together? if so..that would include duplicates which i dont want..i could be wrong..but thats what it looks like to me

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you trying to accomplish but the above would let you go with that. You might need to change a bit for your end result.

Comment: k..i added it to the end of the code part....i'm still trying to think of a better way of saying it..there is just so many things happening haha.

Comment: i did get your thing to work..i left out 1 part..whoops..though..as i suspected..did not get the right answer..a1-7, a2= 7..the problem is..then when they are added up..they are suppose to be 11 at the most, but this gives me something to play around with