# Checking 2 sql columns and displaying result in 1 column pt2

Tags: sql, logic, case

I have 2 tables...they are basically the same except for the column name in one of them because they deal with 2 different names, though.. the data I want is in columns that have the same name. Pretty much what I want to do... is .they also need to be distinct so I don't count duplicates... I can get them as separate tables... but I can't get them together.. I need them in 1 column because of how it is sent to the C3 code page and how it reads it... the structure has already been previously set.. and there are about 5 other statements that are being executed in this one stored procedure like this (also I wasn't the one who set this up). So if this is possible.. let me know please.. I will also paste the exact code I have if you feel like seeing the real life code.. I just tried to simplify it to make it easier to understand. 
I'm going to post some images to hopefully explain it a little better.

Image 1 is what is currently set up:

[image: http://imgur.com/h0rNU]

top part is what is stored in tables.. bottom is more of the result
it basically runs this code to get the bottom

```
DECLARE @id INT;
DECLARE @invest nvarchar(50);
SET @id = '7633';
SET @invest = '';

SELECT 'a' + CONVERT(nvarchar, orderfindings.risk_rating) AS cat, COUNT(DISTINCT orderfindings.prnt_id) AS stat
    FROM orderheader, orderaudits, orderfindings
    WHERE orderheader.id = orderaudits.orderheader_id AND orderaudits.ID = orderfindings.prnt_id
    AND orderheader.id = @id AND orderfindings.risk_rating > 0 AND orderaudits.Investor_Name LIKE '%' + @invest + '%'
    GROUP BY orderfindings.risk_rating
```

If I want agencies instead of findings.. just replace it.. agencies and findings are the 2 tables.. they are the pretty much identical column wise... but I want the result together.. I've tried several ways.. but I can't seem to get it
image 2- the table at the bottom is more what I'm looking for.. it combines them both into 1:

[image: http://imgur.com/a4qXW]

If an order has a finding or agency or both in it.. then it gets marked as a 1 for that risk rating... if it doesn't.. then 0 for that risk rating.. and then sum them all up to see what I got.. any help is appreciated .. I'll clarify what I can if you don't understand;

Edit:
I've been working with it.. .did this http://pastebin.com/117Z2TVh .. got it to display 2 columns.. but still not the right result... I'm getting a1 = 1...a2 = 1... so its not running through all the orders... or it needs a way to count it... I put a sum at beginning of case statement.. erro because of counts... so I took counts out... didn't really work.. any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

;WITH finding AS (select oa.id, oa.Risk_Rating, COUNT (orf.Prnt_ID) findingcount
                    FROM orderaudits oa
                    LEFT JOIN orderfindings orf
                      on oa.ID = orf.Prnt_ID
                    --WHERE oa.risk_rating > 0 and oa.Investor_Name like '%' + @invest + '%'
                   GROUP BY oa.id, oa.Risk_Rating),
      Agency AS (select oa.id, oa.Risk_Rating, COUNT (ora.Prnt_ID) agencycount
                    FROM orderaudits oa
                    LEFT JOIN orderagencies ora
                      on oa.ID = ora.Prnt_ID
                    --WHERE oa.risk_rating > 0 and oa.Investor_Name like '%' + @invest + '%'
                   GROUP BY oa.id, oa.Risk_Rating)
/*
SELECT 'Finding Only', oa.Risk_Rating, COUNT(oa.id) as a, SUM(CASE WHEN f.findingcount > 0 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as b
  FROM orderaudits oa
  LEFT JOIN finding f
    ON oa.id = f.id
  LEFT JOIN orderheader oh
    ON oh.id = oa.orderheader_id
WHERE oh.id = @id and oa.risk_rating > 0 and oa.Investor_Name like '%' + @invest + '%'
GROUP BY oa.Risk_Rating

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Agency Only', oa.Risk_Rating, COUNT(oa.id) as a, SUM(CASE WHEN a.agencycount > 0 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as b
  FROM orderaudits oa
  LEFT JOIN Agency a
    ON oa.id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN orderheader oh
    ON oh.id = oa.orderheader_id
WHERE oh.id = @id and oa.risk_rating > 0 and oa.Investor_Name like '%' + @invest + '%'
GROUP BY oa.Risk_Rating

UNION ALL
*/
--Together
SELECT 'aa' + convert(nvarchar, oa.risk_rating) as cat, SUM(CASE WHEN f.findingcount > 0 OR a.agencycount > 0 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as b
  FROM orderaudits oa
  LEFT JOIN finding f
    ON oa.id = f.id
  LEFT JOIN Agency a
    ON oa.id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN orderheader oh
    ON oh.id = oa.orderheader_id
WHERE oh.id = @id and oa.risk_rating > 0 and oa.Investor_Name like '%' + @invest + '%'
GROUP BY oa.Risk_Rating

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a UNION clause?

If you are not familiar:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

Basically you write two queries returning one of the two columns in question on either side of the UNION and they are returned as one column in the final result set.  If the column names are not the same alias them on either side so that they can be combined in the final unioned result set.

Comment: i actually have tried union..the sql statement i put in..copied it..changed it to agencies..and stuck a union all inbetween..it it doesnt combine them though.. it gives me.. a1 = 5, a2 =2, a2 =3 a2 = 3...which is still wrong...cuz in reality..a1 should be 5, and a2 4...i dont want to add them..or do them seperately..i need the statement to check and see if either of them are true..if yes..add 1..elso..nothing..and go through all the orders..does that help?

Comment: Can you script out your table and data, would be much quicker if I had your exact environment to write the query than trying to imagine it in my head :)

Comment: tbh..not really..there is some sensitive info in some of the table it pulls from..thats why i sorta made the dummy table..well not table..but..the info..sorry.i'm trying to think of a way to do it..best i could do..is to expand upon the dummy layout for you and make the tables how they should be

Comment: added something new..maybe that might help